# Button press to validate multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm doing an MVC application and I need to use one button to validate two fields.

At the moment, I have two buttons and two javascript functions, one two validate each field individually.

**Function 1:**

```
<button onclick="callApi()" id="userButton">@Resources.Resources.ButtonFind</button>
<div id="user">
<p>@Resources.Resources.UserName:
</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"  id="select_user">
function callApi() {
    var userName = $('#search_employee').val();
    /* call the api */
    $.ajax('OneUserInfo', {
        data: {
            strUserName: userName
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //this will happen on success of request
            $('#DataUser').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
        },
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,   //important! especially for IE...
        async: false  //set to false if you want th UI to wait for the ajax call;
    });
}

function GO() {
    location.href = '/Home/NewspaperStatus?name=value';
}

</script>
```

**Function 2:**

```
<div id="datePicker">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</div>
<div id="date">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>@Resources.Resources.Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script name="select_date" id="select_date">

  $(function () {
      intDate = Date;
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          //defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: "01/01/2008"
      });
      $("button.action").click(function () {
          //console.log(select_date);
          var date = $('#datepicker').val().toString();
          $.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  //this will happen on success of request
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
      });
  });
</script>
<button class="action" type="button" id="dateButton">@Resources.Resources.ButtonFind</button>
<br>
```

How can I write the code so that both fields are validated on the same button press?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Thank you guys. So if I understand you correctly I have to do something like this:

```
 <div id="date">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <p>@Resources.Resources.Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 <script name="select_date" id="select_date">

  $(function getInfo() {
      intDate = Date;
      var userName = $('#search_employee').val();
      $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          //defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          minDate: "01/01/2008"
      });
      $("button.action").click(function () {
          //console.log(select_date);
          var date = $('#datepicker').val().toString();
          $.ajax('EmployeeDate', {
              data: {
                  strUserName: userName,
                  strDate: date
              },
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  //this will happen on success of request
                  $('#DataUser').html(data);
              },
              error: function () {
                  console.log("error handler when ajax request fails... ");
              },

          });
      });
  });
</script>
<button onclick="getInfo()" id="userButton">@Resources.Resources.ButtonFind</button>
<br>
```

Anyway I should be doing something wrong, cause I cant execute the code. "function is not defined" error. There is something on the code that is not right? Thanks!

Comment: The two functions change the element '#DataUser'... what is supposed to do this future unique function on success?

Comment: It should be a combination of both values. Now, both separtley change the dataUser, but if there is only one button, that only button should change it

Comment: Well, I would do just one ajax call, changing the controller that takes the request... otherwise, as you can see in answers, you could use 'promises' to make two ajax calls and print the data after the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it. for example you can combine / extent your data property and from server you return which property was invalid and handle that in ajax. But if you cant/dont want to combine you can also use Jquery promise functionality [api.jquery.com/promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/). With this you can have more control what to do next when the previous call was successful / failed etc..

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change that to have only one function with one button?

You can do that by calling one function inside another

```
function callApi() {
   $.ajax({
   success:function(response){
      //  Here you can call the second function 
    }
  })
}
```

> can I change that to have only one function

The second function have a separate ajax call, you can use jquery [**when**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to chain the two ajax calls inside one single function.
Also you have to put the datepicker related code in appropriate position either in side success of first ajax or before executing any ajax call